# Change constraint target class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, constraints

I designed lots of constraints for my iOS app. Now the app works properly on all iPhone in portrait mode. I designed the constraints for the `xCompact hRegular` class. I realized, unfortunately only now, that all those constraints would be perfect also for all iPad in portrait. So, how can I change the constraints target class without recreating all of them for the more generic `wAny hAny` class? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select a constraint. In the last property in the attributes inspector, XCode shows you a list of check boxes with the size classes for which the constraint is active. The first check box represents `wAny hAny`, select it and repeat this for each constraint.